# Limiting Docker RAM use?

Tags: docker

I don't care how much memory on-disk my container uses, or how many swaps, but would like to limit its access to RAM.

How do I do that, once I've created the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your container with the `-m` (aka `--memory`) switch and specify the maximum amount of RAM you'd like to be available to your running container.

> `-m` or `--memory=`   The maximum amount of memory the container can use. If you set this option, the minimum allowed value is 4m (4 megabyte).

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory

And here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources